# Error calling HttpClient.GetAsync: The underlying connection was closed

Tags: asp.net, asynchronous, asp.net-web-api

I have an asp.net MVC website which is consuming a rest api to receive it's data. I'm using asynchronous tasks to perform the requests as there can be many on each page. After a while of uptime the website has been throwing the following error when trying to receive data.

*The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send.*

I read that this could be due to the maxconnection settings on the web.config but increasing this doesn't seem to make much difference.

I'm also using caching to reduce the load on the api. The task is cached so the result can be used later.

The only way I've found to fix this is by recycling the application pool. Any help would be appreciated.

```
/* Code from page_load */

var currenciesTask = ApiClient.GetAsync<CurrencyListWrapper>("currencies");
var blogArticleTask = ApiClient.GetAsync<BlogArticleListWrapper>("blog/articles", "limit=10");
var seoPageTask = ApiClient.GetAsync<SEOPageListWrapper>("seopages");

await Task.WhenAll(currenciesTask, blogArticleTask, seoPageTask);


/* Code from data access later */

public class ApiClient : HttpClient
{
  public static Task<T> GetAsync<T>(string operation, string query = null, bool cache = true)
  {
    // Check if task is in cache
    string cacheName = null;

    if (cache)
    {
      cacheName = String.Format("{0}_{1}_{2}", operation, query ?? String.Empty, App.GetLanguage());

      var cachedTask = HttpRuntime.Cache[cacheName];

      if (cachedTask != null)
      {
        return (Task<T>)cachedTask;
      }

    }

    // Get data task
    var task = GetAsyncData<T>(operation, query);

    // Add to cache if required
    if (task != null && cache)
    {
      App.AddToCache(cacheName, task);
    }

    return task;
  }

  public static async Task<T> GetAsyncData<T>(string operation, string query = null)
  {
    using (ApiClient client = new ApiClient())
    {
      string url;

      if (query != null)
      {
        url = String.Format("{0}?{1}", operation, query);
      }
      else
      {
        url = String.Format("{0}", operation);
      }

      var response = await client.GetAsync(url);

      return (await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<T>());
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This error seems to originate from IIS. Most of the time this is something specific that messes with the Protocol. Causes can be SSL related or Framework compatitibility...

**couple questions**: **1)** are you using SSL? **2)** What version of .Net does your app pool use in IIS?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yes we are using SSL on the website and the web service it's connecting to. The application pool is using .Net v4.0.30319.

Comment: Check your certificate, your cert registration with IIS, check the bindings. If all looks fine you may even try removing and reregistering cert. I suspect it's  confused by protocol. protocol problems cause excess handshakes and lead to zombie Request threads.

Comment: If your administration can trace request and response check the protocol. If it's not SSL 3, that's the problem. Fiddler may help with that.

Comment: Are you sure ur app is running 4.0 and not 4.5?

Comment: What happens if you disable your cache of the tasks?

Comment: It is running version .NET 4.5.50709. I will try reinstalling the certificate and see if that helps. I don't think it's the caching as the error is coming from the initial connection to the API before it's cached.

Comment: I have checked the SSL and all appears fine. The only issue we had with the SSL is that we used a single certificate across multiple domains (using the subject alternate name) and websites in IIS by using the command prompt to set the bindings (appcmd set site /site.name:"api.somewhere.com" /+bindings.[protocol='https',bindingInformation='*:443:api.somewhere.com']).

Comment: You should try disabling Keep Alive on your website in IIS, that would probably fix your issue.

Comment: Thanks. I've tried disabling Keep Alive on client and API sites and it's still happening. I get the error message "The underlying connection was closed" more often now than ever. I keep having to recycle application pools to get the site back up. Once I get this error it continues on all further requests.

Comment: Your first three calls could be a batch? That will reduce no of calls by three times.

Comment: Thanks @AnilKumar I thought that Task.WhenAll would group these requests together. How would you batch these requests?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is wrong,

> The task is cached so the result can be used later.

You are supposed to cache result, not the task. At end of first execution, your `HttpClient` is closed and when you try to retrieve cached task, it will not work.

```
public class ApiClient : HttpClient
{
  public static async Task<T> GetAsync<T>(string operation, string query = null, bool cache = true)
  {
    // Check if task is in cache
    string cacheName = null;

    if (cache)
    {
      cacheName = String.Format("{0}_{1}_{2}", operation, query ?? String.Empty, App.GetLanguage());

      T cachedResult = (T)HttpRuntime.Cache[cacheName];

      if (cachedResult!= null)
      {
        return Task.FromResult(cachedResult);
      }

    }

    // Get data task
    var result = await GetAsyncData<T>(operation, query);

    // Add to cache if required
    if (result != null && cache)
    {
      App.AddToCache(cacheName, result);
    }

    return result;
  }

  public static async Task<T> GetAsyncData<T>(string operation, string query = null)
  {
    using (ApiClient client = new ApiClient())
    {
      string url;

      if (query != null)
      {
        url = String.Format("{0}?{1}", operation, query);
      }
      else
      {
        url = String.Format("{0}", operation);
      }

      var response = await client.GetAsync(url);

      return (await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<T>());
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I will try this. There's one line I had to correct to get it to work. return await Task.FromResult(cachedResult);

Answer (score 0):

Akash could be right.
But it seems more or less connection issue with application pool. Set the connection limit 0 to make it unlimited at application pool.
Have a finally block in you code, and

```
gc.collect();
```

garbage collection method to be called to remove unused connections to make space for other connection.

Comment: Thanks, the connection limit on the application pool is already set to 0. I will investigate the garbage collection.